# Discrete Wavelet Transform Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, wavelet, dwt

I am trying to use the functions provided in the Matlab Wavelet Toolbox to create a multi-level discrete wavelet decomposition of an image, extracting the coefficients, manipulating them, and recomposing them back into the image.

I tried using a number of functions but none of them seem to do what I need. These are the steps to do this.

1. Use wavedec2 to decompose the image into [C,S].
   `[C,S] = wavedec2(X,N,Lo_D,Hi_D)`
2. I then must use detcoef2 to extract the detail coefficients from [C,S]. [C,S] is the 'wavelet decomposition structure', it does not represent the actual coefficients such as cD, cH, cV.
   `[H,V,D] = detcoef2('all',C,S,N)`
3. Manipulate the data
4. Reconstruct [C,S] ???? no function does this.
5. Use waverec2 to recompose the original image.
   `X = waverec2(C,S,Lo_R,Hi_R)`

The problem is with step 4. There is no function that recreates the [C,S] and I can't call the function waverec2 because it needs the manipulated version of C and S.

Do I not need wavedec2 and waverec2? Perhaps should I just use detcoef2 and upcoef2?

Someone with some experience with DWT could solve this in a minute, I am fairly new to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm curious as to why you can't use [`dwt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/dwt2.html) for computing the 2D DWT of images.  What you have there is a lot more work than what you should be doing.  `dwt2` is much more suitable to do what you want.  You'd call `dwt2` like so:

```
[LL,LH,HL,HH] = dwt2(X,Lo_D,Hi_D);
```

`X` is your image, and `Lo_D` and `Hi_D` are your low-pass and high-pass filters you want to apply to the image.  `LL` is the low-passed version of the image, where the horizontal and vertical directions are low-passed, `LH` is where the vertical direction is low-passed and the horizontal direction is high-passed, `HL` is the vertical direction is high-passed and the horizontal direction is low-passed, and `HH` is where both directions are high-passed.  As such `LH`, `HL` and `HH` are the detail coefficients while `LL` contains the structure.

You can also specify the filter you want with a string as the second parameter:

```
[LL,LH,HL,HH] = dwt2(X,'wname');
```

`'wname'` is a string that specifies what filter you want.  You can type in `help wfilters` to see what filters are available.

For example, by doing using `cameraman.tif` from MATLAB's system path, we can do a one level 2D DWT (using the Haar wavelet) and show all of the components like so:

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
[LL, LH, HL, HH] = dwt2(im2double(im), 'haar');
imshow([LL LH; HL HH], []);
```

I use [`im2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html) to convert the image to double precision to ensure accuracy.  We get this image:

[image]

Note that the image is subsampled by 2 in order to produce the decompositions of `LL, LH, HL` and `HH`.

Once you have these components, you can certainly manipulate them to your heart's content.  Once you manipulate them, you can simply use [`idwt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/idwt2.html) like so:

```
Y = idwt2(LL,LH,HL,HH,Lo_R,Hi_R); %//or
Y = idwt2(LL,LH,HL,HH,'wname');
```

The four components are assumed to be `double`, and so you can convert the images back to whatever type that was representing the image.  Assuming your image was `uint8`, you can do: `Y = im2uint8(Y);` to convert back.

This should hopefully be what you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks, I had this way originally, and thanks for the time of typing all that up! I basically wanted to try wavedec2 because it allows you to pass in the number of levels of decomposition N, but it is easier to just use dwt2 manually and if N>1, if N>2, etc.

Comment: @Bonapart3 - Ahh I understand.  If you want a multi-level decomposition, you can most certainly put `dwt2` in a loop.  I didn't understand what you wanted, but now I do.  Thanks!